# How I increase Text to speech volume over other background music apps Android

Tags: text-to-speech, voice, background-music

I use Audio Manager to fade Text to speech voice command and Background music for a short time. I request audio focus using AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK flag.

It will fade two voice out puts but not very clear. I want to increase Text to speech volume higher and background music volume lower. After finish the speech it should be recovered.

I try setStreamVolume as well. But it control both the voices. Is there a way to increase Text to speech volume without increasing background. Any help is appreciated.

```
var vol = mAudioManager?.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

tts!!.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {

                override fun onStart(utteranceId: String?) {
                    mAudioManager?.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,vol!!+3,0)
                }

                override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                    mAudioManager?.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener)
                    mAudioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                    mAudioManager?.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,vol!!,0)
                }

                override fun onError(utteranceId: String?) {
                }
            })
```

```
----

AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK)
----
```

Comment: Acctually,I need to know how can I amplify the text to speech volume level.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am interested in  this topic